# MyPy Version 0.812 Not Excluding setup.py Files

Tags: python, mypy

I've been unable run MyPy without it complaining about duplicate modules. I found [this existing SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67130900/why-is-mypy-checking-files-that-ive-excluded) and tried both to exclude `setup.py` and to have MyPy not follow imports, but I'm still experiencing the following output:

> mypy --follow-imports skip --exclude 'setup' --exclude 'setup.py' --exclude setup --exclude '/setup$'  --exclude '/setup.py$' --exclude '/**init**.py$' .

> test-ghilston-python-cookiecutter/example_package_with_logging/setup.py: error: Duplicate module named 'setup' (also at './test-ghilston-python-cookiecutter/example_package/setup.py')

> test-ghilston-python-cookiecutter/example_package_with_logging/setup.py: note: Are you missing an **init**.py? Alternatively, consider using --exclude to avoid checking one of them.

> Found 1 error in 1 file (errors prevented further checking)

I've added quite a few `--exclude` parameters to showcase attempting to pass in a variety of different ways to represent the file `setup.py`.

One can read the [official documentation describing the `exclude` flag here](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command_line.html#cmdoption-mypy-exclude), which I believe I am following correctly.

Any help is appreciated, as clearly this is user error on my part.