# Mypy directory exclude in pyproject.toml file not working for pre-commit

Tags: python, mypy, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit.com, pyproject.toml

For a project structure:

```
proj
|-pyproject.toml
|-.pre-commit-config.yml
|-scripts
|-src
|-tests
```

I want to exclude the `test` and `scripts` within the `pyproject.toml` file as follows:

```
[tool.mypy]
follow-imports=false
exclude = [
    'tests/', 'scripts/', 'ml/'
    ]
```

However, after running the:
 `pre-commit run --all-files`

from the `proj` directory root mypy repoert still reports errors from those directories.

the pre-commit yml is as follows:
`

```
repos:
  - repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit-hooks
    rev: v3.2.0
    hooks:
    -   id: trailing-whitespace
    -   id: end-of-file-fixer
    -   id: check-yaml
    -   id: check-added-large-files- repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/mirrors-mypy
    rev: v1.8.0  # Use the sha / tag you want to point at
    hooks:
      - id: mypy
        args: [--config-file=pyproject.toml]
```

- many variants of regex not working
- [Why is mypy checking files that I've excluded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67130900/why-is-mypy-checking-files-that-ive-excluded) is not answering my question and has no accepted answer..